# Mínimo de un valor en python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código en Python usando Sublime Text 3.2

```
print("Probabilidad de que un atacante cambie cierta transaccion")
        import math
        z=int(input("Introduce el numero de bloques z= "))
        q=float(input("Introduce la potencia del atacante q= "))
        p=1-q
        while z>=0:
            suma1=0
            lamda=z*(q/p)
            for i in range(z+1):
                expo=math.exp(-lamda)
                num1=pow(lamda,i)*expo/math.factorial(i)
                num2=1-pow(q/p,z-i)
                poisson=num1*num2
                suma1=suma1 + poisson
                P=1-suma1
            if P<0.001:
                print(z,P)
            z=z-1
```

de escoger el mínimo z con la última condición, ¿Alguien podría hacerme el favor de darme alguna sugerencia?. Estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Hola! No es clara tu pregunta. ¿Qué está sucediendo actualmente? ¿Qué debería suceder? ¿Con qué datos pruebas? Añade esta información editando tu pregunta, por favor

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que si obtendrás varios valores de z dado que la ultima condición puede ser cierta mas de una vez y que quieres el minimo valor de todos esos valores, si es asi, puedes pasar esos valores a una lista o array y aplicar min() a la lista, te dejo un ejemplo

```
    #Considerar una lista vacia llamada valores_z
    if P<0.001:
        valores_z.append(z)
    print(min(valores_z))
```

Si esa no es tu pregunta, por favor edita, quedo atento

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo había solucionado y efectivamente era creando una lista vacía y después ir agregando los valores de z donde P<0.001 y después usar min de esa lista.